# How to limit MySQL display data in different screen sizes Bootsrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm new to the Bootstrap. currently I'm trying to complete a small project. In my project I have some product to be displayed (3 products in a row).

My problem is when I re-size the screen to (Mobile landscape 480x320). I want to display two product records in Mobile landscape mode, but up-to now it only give me a one product show in Mobile landscape mode. But in desktop mode it is working perfectly by showing me 3 products.

I use a MySQL query to fetch data into a div which has a class "col-sm-4". I change product image width 100% even in view-port, but it didn't work out.

How can I achieve this? I'm using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: thanks for your support too Mr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:
Add row class as

```
col-xs-6 col-sm-4
```

Comment: thanks satya you it works perfectly! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**

> Try this: Add row class as

**

```
col-xs-6 col-sm-4
```

Comment: thanks Mahendra. got the same working answer from you too